# cut: |: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, unix, cut

```
while read line
    do
        echo $line
        calendar_date=$(cut -d\  -f1 $line)
            hr_of_day=$(cut -d\  -f2 $line)
        echo "date: $calendar_date hr: $hr_of_day"

done < $FILE
```

I am getting the following error:

```
date:  hr:
2011-06-30 | 23
cut: 2011-06-30: No such file or directory
cut: |: No such file or directory
cut: 23: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Have you looked up `cut`'s manual entry? Have you tried to understand the meaning of the error message? What have you tried?

Comment: $line is being read as file parameters.
It is possible to write something like `hr_of_day=$(echo "$line" | cut -d\  -f2)`  if you do not have quotes in your incoming text.

Answer (score 6):

`cut` understands the `$line` argument as a file name. If your shell is bash, you can use the `<<<` here-word:

```bsh
cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "$line"
```

But, there's no need to call external commands, bash can do it with parameter substitution:

```bsh
date=${line%|*}  # Delete from | to the right.
hour=${line#*|}  # Delete up to |.
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this when I ran into a similar issue however in the OP post, you can see that shell would attempt to read the $line as the file for the command.  However I was having the same issue while I was echoing and piping into the command like this:

```
while read line;
   do
      FILE=QRPGLESRC;
      MBR=$(echo "$line" | cut -d" " -f1);
      PATH=$(echo "$FILE.$MBR" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]');
      echo $PATH;
done < listofstuff
```

This would echo out:

```
./parse.sh: line 8: cut: No such file or directory
./parse.sh: line 9: tr: No such file or directory
```

After some headache, I realized it wasn't the variable that it was thinking was a file, but the command.  I used absolute paths for the commands (using which to find them) and that fixed my issue:

```
while read line;
   do
      FILE=QRPGLESRC;
      MBR=$(echo "$line" | /usr/bin/cut -d" " -f1);
      PATH=$(echo "$FILE.$MBR" | /usr/bin/tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]');
      echo $PATH;
done < listofstuff;
```

Answer (score 1):

on mac os x terminal

```
test="$(echo '1\2\2016' | cut -d '\' -f3-)" 
echo "year:$test"
prints year from test with an echo string
year:2016  
or
echo "year:"$(echo '1\2\2016' | cut -d '\' -f3-)""
prints year from test with an echo string
year:2016
```

try this (similar to above)

```
calendar_date="$(cut -d '\' -f1 $line)"
hr_of_day="$(cut -d '\' -f2 $line)"
echo "date: $calendar_date hr: $hr_of_day"
```

for input reads this works with echo

```
while read x
do
    echo $x | cut -c3,7    #echo $x | cut -c3,7 (for range of letters)
done
```

Comment: $line is being read as file parameters.

Comment: edited first post please try and let us know...